# What are the requirements for using Stack Overflow content on Wikipedia?

Tags: discussion, licensing, wikipedia

Sometimes an answer is written like an encyclopedic article, it contains a great example/paragraph or a tag wiki is really sophisticated (such that you could use it or use parts of it in a Wikipedia article) - thus my question:

What are the requirements for using Stack Overflow content on Wikipedia?

I understand that both sites use the same Creative Commons license (CC by-sa 3.0), but how should attribution work in practice?

Is it all right to import content into a Wikipedia article and attribute the source in full detail - but then remove the attribution in a later revisions of the article? I mean, it is still there in the history ...

Comment: Related: [Would it be OK to paste content from Wikipedia into a popular empty tag-wiki?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79000)

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28905/answers-from-the-trilogy-as-references-in-wikipedia

Comment: The easiest would be to ask the respective author (using a comment) if he is okay with including the content in a Wikipedia article with only a source mention in the revision history (without explicit mention beside the included text).

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia, as with all things, has [policies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Plagiarism#Sources_under_copyleft) and [templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:CCBYSASource) for satisfying the requirements of various licenses. I think you're likely to have less trouble with licensing and attribution as you will with Wikipedia's more general policy.

(*Edit:* actually, when I looked a little closer at how that template I linked to works, it wouldn't satisfy the Stack Overflow license requirements, since it adds [nofollow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) to the links it creates.)

Citing Stack Overflow is, theoretically, a [no-no](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Verifiability#Self-published_sources_.28online_and_paper.29).  As for *including* content from Stack Overflow in a Wikipedia article, it obviously depends what's being included and for what prupose.

Depending somewhat on the sources cited in the answer or tag wiki itself, Stack Overflow content is likely to be considered [original research](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:No_original_research). Something from Stack Overflow that itself cites [reliable sources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:RS) may be OK, but things will depend on how the content is being used in the article.

In practice, of course, many smaller or more "niche" articles [skirt lots of rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:IAR). As far as what would be acceptable on the Wikipedia side, of course, the better place to ask would probably be at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Village_pump).